# Determining all the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, where R is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers, group-homomorphism

I think I have this question figured out almost completely, but I'm a little worried about using a certain notation.

Suppose $\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} R$ is a ring homomorphism. Observe that $\phi(1) = \phi(1\cdot1) = \phi(1)\phi(1) = \phi(1)^2$. Thus, $\phi(1)-\phi(1)^2 = 0$ and moreover $\phi(1)(\phi(1) - 1) = 0$. Since R has no zero divisors, it follows that $\phi(1) = 0$ or $\phi(1) = 1$. Hence, $\phi$ is either trivial, or $\phi(1) = 1$. In the latter case, $\phi$ is entirely determined in the following way: for any $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, 
\begin{equation}
\phi(r) = \phi(\stackrel{r \, \,times}{1 \, + \, ... \, + \, 1}) = \, \stackrel{r \, \,times}{\phi(1) \, + \, ... \, + \, \phi(1)} = r\cdot\phi(1)
\end{equation}

My trepidation arises with the last equality. It doesn't seem to me that multiplication of an integer r by $\phi(1)$ is necessarily well defined in an arbitrary integral domain R. That being said, I don't see any other way to denote iterated addition. Is this a well-defined notation, and if not, how should I represent iterated addition in R?

Comment: Most authors use the convention that a ring homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$, in which case for any ring $R$ whatsoever there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$. Multiplication of an integer $r$ by $\phi(1)$ is well-defined in any abelian group: it is, by definition, $\phi(1)$ added to itself $r$ times.

Comment: Most, but not all. In particular, Dummit and Foote only require that a ring homomorphism preserve the structure of the operations between rings. I understand what you're saying about an integer multiplied by an element in abelian group being well defined, but isn't the notation a little confusing when an actual multiplicative structure is placed on the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a ring with unity everything works fine. You have an action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $R$ namely if $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ we define $mr$ as you said above.

This is because every ring has an abelian group structure with the sum.

Returning to your question, if you avoid a morphism that sends everything to zero the rest of homomorphisms are determined by the image of 1.

Comment: So, in a sense, the "multiplication" by an integer is only a notational convenience in abelian groups in the same way that exponentiation denotes iterated multiplication? Is there ever any ambiguity with this notation when a multiplicative structure is placed on the abelian group?

Comment: If you have $r_1,r_2 \in R$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ you can of course think of $m·r_1r_2$ and still makes sense.  It's notation that reflects the idea that summing n times is an abelian group concept not exclusive to integers.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. It's certainly clear to me what it means; I was just worried that it might confuse others. So, formally, this is an instance of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on R? Is the particular action in this case the action iterated addition? I guess that would make sense because such an action would certainly satisfy the identity and compatibility constraints.

Comment: Maybe if you read the definition of an $R$ Module it could be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. :)